# Likert scale plot and levels

Tags: r, visualization

I'm using the liket package (http://reg.statistik-forum.de/).

In my case: Two questions, 13 observations, useing a 5-point scale ("Very dissatisfied","Dissatisfied","Neither","Satisfied","Very satisfied").

```
q1 <- c(3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4, 3)
q2 <- c(3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)
q1 <- factor(q1, levels = c(0,1,2,3,4), labels = c("Very dissatisfied","Dissatisfied","Neither","Satisfied","Very satisfied"))
q2 <- factor(q2, levels = c(0,1,2,3,4), labels = c("Very dissatisfied","Dissatisfied","Neither","Satisfied","Very satisfied"))
q.set <- cbind(q1, q2)
require(grid)
require(lattice)
require(latticeExtra)
require(HH)
likert(q.set, horizontal = TRUE, main = "Satisfaction persons")
```

Problem 1: What to change, so the levels in the plot are correct ('very satisfied' not 'q1') and two questions are analyzed not the 13 observations?

Problem 2: Setting the levels of the vectors q1 and q2 to 'levels = c(0,1,2,3,4)', changes the vectors by +1 (q1: c(4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 2, 5, 5, 4)). Is it not possible to set the level '0'?

This is the plot:

[image: Likert scale]